# The correct negative form of "I would rather"

Tags: grammaticality, negation, would-rather

What sentence(s) is correct:

"I would like to go out"

1. "I'd rather you don't"
2. "I'd rather you didn't"
3. "I'd rather you not"

I tend to think that 1/ and 2/ are correct but as for 3/ I am not so sure.

Answer (score -2):

1 and 2 are both correct English, but with different meaning. 1 is close to forbidding the person to go out, while 2 just states what I prefer.

3 is not right, but will be understood as meaning either 1 or 2.

Comment: Intriguing; I'd disagree. I'd say that 2 is best because it's subjunctive, and that 1 (while common enough) is not. Meanwhile, I feel like 3 is a valid usage that I associate with British usage, but that's just my feeling...

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/id-rather-you-didnt-dont-not.861522/ https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rather+you+don%27t%2Crather+you+didn%27t&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crather%20you%20do%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crather%20you%20did%20not%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I’d rather you not misportray 1 as a correct answer when it is anything but that. As a native speaker, I find (1) ungrammatical. (2) and (3) are both perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I hear 1. often enough, AND as a teacher I would mark it wrong. 2 and 3 are fine

Comment: I consider (2) the only idiomatic version.